# REST : how do you handle the rest_no_route error?

Tags: errors, rest-api, json

i'm playing with the REST api and when doing some REST requests I got sometimes what I want, and sometimes this response generated by [rest_ensure_response()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_ensure_response/) :

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    },
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method"
}
```

...But how do you deal with that response, since it is returned as a simple JSON object (or array).  It is not a WP_Error object that I could check.

Here's how I do actually :

```
function api_request($url){

    $request = wp_remote_get($url);
    if (is_wp_error($request)) return $request;

    $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    if (is_wp_error($response)) return $response;

    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    //handle errors ?
    if ( $code = wpsstm_get_array_value('code',$response) ){
        $message = wpsstm_get_array_value('message',$response);
        $data = wpsstm_get_array_value('data',$response);
        $error = new WP_Error($code,$message,$data );

        $this->debug_log($error,'query API error');

        return $error;
    }

    return $response;

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Well, what's your code for making the API request? And what exactly do you mean by, "handle"?

Comment: @SallyCJ : I just edited te question

Comment: I think you are already dealing properly with the response/error - when the response body is a JSON object with a `code`, `message` and `data.status` other than `400`, you can assume the REST API returned a `WP_Error` but of course as a string.

Comment: @SallyCJ, yes, that is it. So I can rely on code + message + data.status ?

Comment: Yes, you can, if the REST API endpoint uses `rest_ensure_response()` to return the response. So you could do something like `if ( response.data && response.data.status >= 400 )` to check if it's an error. Btw, sorry about the "other than 400" in my previous comment... I actually meant to say, "equals to or greater than `400`".

Answer (score 1):

I dug in the codex and found some interesting functions.
This is how I finally did it :

```
function api_request($api_url = null, $params=null,$method = 'GET'){

    if (!$api_url){
        return new WP_Error('no_api_url',"Missing API URL");
    }

    //Create request
    $request = WP_REST_Request::from_url( $api_url );

    //Method
    $request->set_method( $method );

    //params
    switch($method){
        case 'GET':
            $request->set_query_params($params);
        break;
        case 'POST':
            $request->set_body_params($params);
        break;
    }

    //Get response
    $response = rest_do_request( $request );

    if ( $response->is_error() ) {
        return $response->as_error();
    }

    //Get datas
    $datas = $response->get_data();

    return $datas;

}
```